# Cart quantity update but row total problem

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

I just create a simple module for cart quantity update (code give bellow).
My update link like that I call to ajax.
http://example.com/ajaxcart/ajaxcart/quantitichange/item/55/qty/4
It's quantity update fine but I need to subtotal after quantity update. But their is problem. `getRowTotal` function return which loaded `checkout/cart/` 
example my current cart

```
itemId 55 Price:5  Qty:2   RowTotal:10
```

Then I hit 
http://example.com/ajaxcart/ajaxcart/quantitichange/item/55/qty/4
It's should return

```
{"s":"Stock updated","subtotal":"20.0000"}
```

But not that It's return

```
{"s":"Stock updated","subtotal":"10.0000"}
```

If i refresh `checkout/cart/` page and again hit ajax URL then It's return correct. That means Quantity update. But If I need subtotal then I need to refresh cart page manually.

*My code*

```
    public function quantitichangeAction(){
    $jsArray = array();
    $itemId = intval($this->getRequest()->getparam('item'));
    $qty = intval($this->getRequest()->getparam('qty'));
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    $getItem=false;
    foreach($cart as $item){
        if($item->getItemId()==$itemId){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            if ($product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()) {
                $qtyStock = intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty());
                if($qtyStock>=$qty){
                    $item->setQty($qty);
                    $item->save();
                    $jsArray['s']='Stock updated';
                    $jsArray['subtotal']=$item->getRowTotal();
                }
                else{
                    $jsArray['e']='Product Stock not abailable';
                }
            }
            else{
                $jsArray['e']='Product Stock not abailable';
            }
        }
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($jsArray));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to recollect quote totals by running this after saving quote item:

```
$item->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
```

Comment: You saved my week and my mental health! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code :

```
if($qtyStock >= $qty) {
    $item->setQty($qty);
    $item->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    $jsArray['s']='Stock updated';
    $jsArray['subtotal']=$item->getRowTotal();
}
```

Call to `setCartWasUpdated` will force Magento to re-calculate totals for the cart.

Comment: No same things. If I want to see update then required `cart` page refresh. Otherwise It's Keep Old one.